# Swift: Class Type does not have member <var>

Tags: swift

I have following code snippets:

```
protocol UpdateUIFromNativeListenerItf {
    func triggerUI()
}

class WmBuildGroupsTask{

var mUfn:UpdateUIFromNativeListenerItf?

  init(){/* ... */}

 // ...

 class func triggerRegister( ufn: UpdateUIFromNativeListenerItf ) {   
        mUfn = ufn // WmBuildGroupsTask.Type does not have `mUfn`
  }     
}
```

Form other class I call:

```
var ufn:UpdateUIFromNativeListenerItf = self    
WmBuildGroupsTask.triggerRegister(ufn)
```

How can I pass delegate to static method?

Do I need create singleton for class `WmBuildGroupsTask`?

I tried also to write `class var mUfn:UpdateUIFromNativeListenerItf?`

But get: `Class var not yet supported`

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static stored properties are not supported in swift classes (yet), but they are in structs. So you can create an inline private struct and define your static properties there:

```
class WmBuildGroupsTask{
    private struct Static {
        static var mUfn:UpdateUIFromNativeListenerItf?
    }

    init(){/* ... */}

    // ...

    class func triggerRegister( ufn: UpdateUIFromNativeListenerItf ) {
        Static.mUfn = ufn // WmBuildGroupsTask.Type does not have `mUfn`
    }     
}
```

The downside is that you have to access the static property prefixing it with the struct name - but I guess that's an acceptable tradeoff.

There is also another obvious way to solve the problem: turn the class into a struct, so obvious that it's enough to just mention it. Just a consideration: structs and classes are not interchangeable, they have their own pros and cons.

Comment: Ok, got it, similar to singleton definition. As I understand even if class doesn't have instance created or I have several instances, I can pass delegate once and be sure that this var has value != nil, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you initialize it before using

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a member variable in a static context. `mUfn` is stored for an instance of your class, not for the class itself.

Comment: I know that, how can I create `mUfn` in my case? thanks